In Flutter i want to Extend My Screen over the Notch in Landscape mode
By Default The Screen is Extended Over the Notch in Portrait Mode, Same Like that i want my screen to extend over the notch  in  Landscape Mode.
as some one suggested like this, it does not worked at all.
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>

